# Why chain of trust is ok with different CA?

Tags: ssl-certificate, keystore, ca

I have a `.keystore` file and Tomcat's configuration is: *keystore=*`.keystore` and *truststore=*`.keystore`
The `.keystore` contains a *PrivateKeyEntry* (signed by CA1) and a *trustedCertEntry* (CA1).
Everythink ok so far.
If the *trustedCertEntry* would not be present when importing server certificate, I would get:
  `Failed to establish chain from reply`
When I delete the *trustedCertEntry* (CA1), Tomcat can not start because of:
 `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty`
Now my question: When I delete *trustedCertEntry* CA1 and import a *trustedCertEntry* **CA2**, Tomcat starts and the certificate chain (view in browser) is: The server certificate which is signed by **CA1**.
How can this be possible? I would have expected that Tomcat can not start since the *trustedCertEntry* (CA2) does not match with the *PrivateKeyEntry* since *PrivateKeyEntry* was issued from CA1 and not CA2. And since Tomcat can not start without a *trustedCertEntry*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private key is not issued by CA.
Your server certificate is a pair of public and private key. Based on this key pair certificate request was created and this certificate request was signed by CA1. Certificate is valid in your browser as long as CA1 is in trusted CA in certificate store of your browser.

Changing CA in keystore doesn't affect server certificate.

It looks like at least one CA cert is requirement of SSL engine - I'm guessing that any CA cert (i.e. thawte.com/roots, or self-signed) imported to JKS will work for you - JKS must have at least one.

Comment: When I delete the CA from keystore, Tomcat fails to start. Why Tomcat starts with a *wrong* CA in keystore?

Comment: It looks like the requirement of SSL engine - I'm guessing that any CA cert (i.e. https://www.thawte.com/roots/, or self-signed) imported to JKS will work for you - JKS must have at least one.

Comment: You are right, I deleted CA1 and CA2 and added Thawte root CA and Tomcat starts. Thanks for pointing this out that only one Root CA is required, independent which. Strange.